# Store a ref value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reference

I have a WPF window to modify infos of a client. The infos are stored in a struct:

```cs
public struct ClientInfos
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I give the struct that I want to modify to the window by reference:

```cs
ClientInfosWindow.Show(ref clientInfos);
```

In the viewmodel I have a temporary ClientInfos structure that the user will use when he is in the window, and when he saves his changes, this temporary information is copied to the structure passed by reference.

```cs
class ClientInfosViewModel
{
    public ClientInfosViewModel(ref ClientInfos clientInfos))
    {
        ClientInfos = ref clientInfos;
        ClientInfosTemp = clientInfos;
    }

    private ref ClientInfos ClientInfos { get; set; }
    public ClientInfos ClientInfosTemp { get; set; }

    private void SaveClientInfos()
    {
        ClientInfos = ClientInfosTemp;
        ClientInfosWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

So in the ViewModel constructor I have to store the reference passed in parameter to be able to modify this value in a ViewModel method.

The problem is that it is not possible to make a property of type `ref ClientInfos`.

**Would you have a solution to save this reference in the class?**

Comment: The problem you are facing is that if you pass a ref to a struct to the a method (constructor) of a class. The class is not able to store it. The class lives on the heap and the struct might be on the stack. Means that the struct could be removed from the stack and the class still lives with a corrupt reference to the stack.

Comment: As you correctly found out, you can't store a reference to a value as a member of your class. Jon Skeet listed some solutions in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6253579/9363973). Why are you using a struct to store your `ClientInfos` anyways?

Comment: Use a class instead of a struct - especially if it's mutable!

Comment: Okay I see, I will use a class. 
I used a structure because it allowed me not to code a copy constructor and a Copy method. I need it in order to be able to make a full copy of a ClientInfos object without just making a reference to it.

Comment: @CharrièreMaxime You can get the copy semantics automatically by using a `record` if you're using a recent version of C#/.Net. An immutable record can be declared with a single line of code: `public record ClientInfos(string Firstname, string Lastname, int Age);`